# Limit of a two variable function at the origin

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

How can I show that the limit of the following function, when the variables `{x, y}` tend to zero, is zero? Mathematica gives the error

> {x,y} is not a valid variable.

Domains are $0<x<10$ and $0<y<1$.

```
Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 correctly answers Indeterminate (look at the result of Plot3D[Re[
  Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]]], {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}] ). BTW, my ABBY Lingvo x6 says "welcome". Which grammar do you use?

Comment: Modern poets do not use capital letters in heads, but your question is not a verse.

Comment: @user64494 But if we ContourPlot the function, we see that it tends to zero when the two variables go to zero

Comment: Even Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - 
  y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], {x, y} -> {0, 0}, Direction -> "FromAbove"] produces Indeterminate too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) depends on how you approach `{0, 0}` so it is `Indeterminate`. However, you can imply (or specify) a direction of approach which gives `0` as the limit.

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

Looking at the real part of the function

```
Plot3D[Re[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]]], {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 MaxRecursion -> 4,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The multivariate `Limit` is

```
Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], 
  {x, y} -> {0, 0}]

(* Indeterminate *)
```

or

```
Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], 
  {y, x} -> {0, 0}]

(* Indeterminate *)
```

A nested `Limit` is

```
Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], 
  {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
```

[image]

However, reversing the order of approach

```
Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], 
  {y -> 0, x -> 0}]

(* 0 *)
```

Which is the same as

```
Limit[
 Limit[Cosh[1/Sqrt[y]] Sinh[x/Sqrt[y]] - y Cosh[x/Sqrt[y]], x -> 0],
 y -> 0]

(* 0 *)
```